# Unable to navigate to different page using params

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

Unable to redirect to different page. It throws the following error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'cart-items/448511.16099990235'

Can somebody help?

This is in my app.routing.ts

```
//....
{
 path: 'cart-items/:id',
 component: CartComponent
}
//....
```

This is my html

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-3" href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]=" ['/cart-items', randomUserId]"> ... </a>
```

Comment: Not too sure here, but maybe you can't have the `.` in your userId

Comment: @bugs It is not taking any number too.. I gave 2 and checked but same issue

Comment: Can you show the complete routing? In some cases the order of the elements are important

Comment: Most probably the issue is containing `.` in your params as @bugs said

Comment: Even without point(.) it's not working

Comment: where you have written html code , is it in same module , and have you tried directly like http://localhost/cart-items/1

Comment: yes I tried directly.

Comment: @Esco - so it working right , directly ?

Comment: yes it is working now...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
[routerLink] = " 'cart-items/' + randomUserId"
```

or

```
routerLink = "cart-items/{{card.id}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove href,

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-3" [routerLink]="['/cart-items', randomUserId]"> ... </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is because there is `.` in your params so in order to redirect use navigateByUrl from your controller side like this

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('/cart-items/' + randomUserId)
```

Refer here for more info

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8249

Comment: still it's not working. I removed point(.) and gave some random number, but still not working

Comment: then there must be some another issue, at last try by passing some `string` value instead of number one

Answer (score 0):

you code looks ok just remove  `href="javascript:void(0)"` and try like this

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-3" 
   [routerLink]=" ['/cart-items', randomUserId]"> ... </a>
```

seems like issue with the value you are passing which is `448511.16099990235`, which contains `.` i.e. decimal value

are you sure on the id value ?